# Passing the correct type to addch() [ncurses, Linux]

Tags: swift, ncurses

In following a [tutorial](https://github.com/iachievedit/moreswift) on how to use ncurses with swift I have been facing the error:

```
main.swift:31:15: error: cannot convert value of type 'UInt?' to expected argument type 'chtype' (aka 'UInt32')
        addch(UInt("*"))
              ^~~~~~~~~
```

It complains about the type, but when I change it to UInt32 the error changes to `error: ambiguous use of 'init' addch(UInt32("*"))`

### Question

- How to pass the correct value type to addch?

The entire code for reference:

```
import Foundation
import CNCURSES
import Glibc

enum Signal:Int32 {
case INT   = 2
case WINCH = 28
}

typealias SignalHandler = __sighandler_t

func trap(signum:Signal, action:@escaping SignalHandler) {
  signal(signum.rawValue, action)
}

func getmaxyx(window:UnsafeMutablePointer<WINDOW>, y:inout Int32, x:inout Int32) {
  x = getmaxx(window)
  y = getmaxy(window)
}

func getcuryx(window:UnsafeMutablePointer<WINDOW>, y:inout Int32, x:inout Int32) {
  x = getcurx(window)
  y = getcury(window)
}

func drawbox(numlines:Int32, numcols:Int32) {
  for y in 0...numlines-1 {
    for x in 0...numcols {
      move(y, x)
      if y == 0 || y == numlines-1 {
        addch(UInt("*"))
      } else {
        if x == 0 || x == numcols {
          addch(UInt("*"))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  refresh()
}

[...]

initscr()
noecho()
curs_set(0)
getmaxyx(window:stdscr, y:&maxy, x:&maxx)
drawbox(numlines:maxy, numcols:maxx)
center(text:"Hello world!", numlines:maxy, numcols:maxx)

while true {
  select(0, nil, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the error message, you need to pass a `UInt32` value to `addch(_:)`.

The return type of `UInt("*")` is `UInt?`, and its actual value is always `nil`. (Simple `String` to `UInt` conversion tries to interpret the String as decimal integer.)

When you want a character code as `UInt32`, you may need to write something like this:

```
addch(("*" as UnicodeScalar).value)
```

---

If your code would have many more `addch(_:)` calls, you can define a simple wrapper for it.

For example:

```
func addCh(_ us: UnicodeScalar) {
    addch(us.value)
}

addCh("*")
```

With explicitly annotating as `UnicodeScalar`, String Literals are interpreted as `UnicodeScalar` and its `value` property is of type `UInt32`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct (and [documented type](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html)) is **`chtype`**:

```
   int addch(const chtype ch);
   int waddch(WINDOW *win, const chtype ch);
   int mvaddch(int y, int x, const chtype ch);
   int mvwaddch(WINDOW *win, int y, int x, const chtype ch);
   int echochar(const chtype ch);
   int wechochar(WINDOW *win, const chtype ch);
```

The number of bits in **`chtype`** depends upon the system.  In ncurses' header files, it is by default declared as **`unsigned`**, but that can be overridden when configuring/building ncurses.

X/Open (see [`addch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/addch.html) and [`<curses.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/curses.h.html)) says nothing more explicit than that.

Of course, whatever it happens to be in ***swift*** is an implementation detail of the binding, and unless documented, is subject to change.